# vb.net add values from listbox to textbox via drag&drop AND via double click

Tags: vb.net, winforms, drag-and-drop, double-click

I'm struggling with some functionality I want to use on my **Windows form**.
( Just for info, this is for an AutoDesk Inventor AddIn. )

This is my form layout.
[image: form layout]

### The current workflow

The top 4 list-boxes are filled with available parameter names. The user chooses the parameter(s) he/she wants to use and drags and drops it into one of the driving parameter text-boxes ( marked with the `<1>` label ).

The code that relates to the drag and drop operations

```
Private Sub lstTemp_MouseDown(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) _
    Handles lbModelParameters.MouseDown,
    lbUserParameters.MouseDown,
    lbReferenceParameters.MouseDown,
    lbLinkedParameters.MouseDown

    ' In order to access a specific item in a listbox.itemcollection, you must think of it
    ' as an array  of data or a collection and access it in the same manner by always
    ' letting VB know which item you intend to use by identifying it with its index location
    ' within the collection. And this is better than taking up basket weaving :-)
    lbModelParameters.DoDragDrop(sender.Items(sender.SelectedIndex()).ToString, DragDropEffects.Move)
End Sub

Private Sub txtTemp_DragEnter(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) _
    Handles tbParameter1.DragEnter,
    tbParameter2.DragEnter,
    tbParameter3.DragEnter,
    tbParameter4.DragEnter,
    tbParameter5.DragEnter

    'Check the format of the incoming data and accept it if the destination control is able to handle
    '  the data format

    'Data verification
    If e.Data().GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text) Then
        e.Effect() = DragDropEffects.Move
    Else
        e.Effect() = DragDropEffects.None
    End If

End Sub

Private Sub txtTemp_DragDrop(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) _
    Handles tbParameter1.DragDrop,
    tbParameter2.DragDrop,
    tbParameter3.DragDrop,
    tbParameter4.DragDrop,
    tbParameter5.DragDrop
    'This procedure receives the dragged data once it passes the data verification handled by the DragEnter method

    'Drops the data onto the destination control
    sender.Text() = e.Data().GetData(DataFormats.Text).ToString()

End Sub
```

---

### New functionality

Now I would like to decrease the user mouse movement for ergonomic reasons and speed. But I would also like to keep to the drag and drop functionality. As it can overwrite a value that has already been added by the user.

I would like to be able to `DoubleClick` a item in the listbox, and that item should be added to the first empty textbox. I named my textboxes with a number so it's easy to loop over them all to check if it's empty.

I tried doing it with this code, but my double click event **never** gets fired. It always goes to the drag and drop. How do you do handle this, that the double click gets fired instead of drag drop?

```
Private Sub ParameterAddDoubleClick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) _
    Handles lbModelParameters.DoubleClick,
    lbUserParameters.DoubleClick,
    lbReferenceParameters.DoubleClick,
    lbLinkedParameters.DoubleClick

    Dim oControl As Windows.Forms.ListBox
    oControl = DirectCast(sender, Windows.Forms.ListBox)

    ' Add line in likedparameters listbox
    If oControl.SelectedIndex <> -1 Then

        ' Loop trough all the controls to see if one is empty
        ' if it's empty add parameter, else go to next
        ' if all textboxes are used do nothing.
        For i = 1 To 6

            Dim oTextbox As Windows.Forms.TextBox =
            CType(gbDrivingParameters.Controls("tbParameter" & i),
            Windows.Forms.TextBox)

            If oTextbox.TextLength = 0 Then
                ' Add the sender item into the linked listbox
                oTextbox.Text = oControl.Items.Item(oControl.SelectedIndex)
            End If
        Next
    End If
End Sub
```

---

I hope my question is clear, and well prepared. If there is additional information needed, please let me know in a comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mousedown triggers the DoDragDrop, wich stops the doubleclick-event from firing.

To identify if a user doubleclicks or wants to perform a dragdrop, consider the following:

```
Private Sub ListBox1_MouseDown(sender As Object, e As MouseEventArgs) Handles ListBox1.MouseDown
    ' Determine whether we are performing a drag operation OR a double click
    If e.Clicks = 1 Then
        TextBox1.Text = "mousedown"
    Else
        TextBox1.Text = "dblclick"
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi! thanks for the fast reply! This answer works, but I wonder, are there other possibilities too? I found this but, it's more complex to use https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171543%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: And it does exactly the same. It uses a 'flag' to evaluate if it's first or second click (isFirstClick) combined with an interval (SystemInformation.DoubleClickTime). Both those methods are also in your MouseEventArgs above.  

If it's to much hassle: consider the 'down arrow' key for an drag-drop alternative? User selects item, presses downarrow and then it appears below.

Comment: correction: Down arrow for double click alternative. I agree that it is not as user friendly as a doubleclick, but people (at least the ones working with my programs) generally don't complain about these workarounds.

Comment: Thanks for that extra input, the double click was a request from the end-users, so I was aiming for it. Down key, is a good alternative! Have a nice day!